# How can I map request params to object?

Tags: java, mapping, dropwizard

Can you suggest simple way to map request params to "ParamsObject"? So I wanna create for requests params class and automatically map request params to instance of this class:

```
@GET
public MyReturnClass trololo(MyRequestClass request) {
    return new MyReturnClass(request.getSort(), request.getSearch());
}

class MyRequestClass {
   private int sort;
   private String search;
   ...
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245712/unable-to-send-json-object-to-rest-web-service/21245771#21245771 if you want to use json.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, the code that you need to read a parameter in the method call is as follows

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void nameOfMethod(@RequestParam(value = "value", required = true) final Long id){
}
```

Comment: No, I want to map multiple parameters into single object of custom class. Something similar to `@BeanParam` from Jersey 2.0

Answer (score 0):

First of all for GET request , you need to pass parameter in Basic Datatype

```
    @GET 
public MyReturnClass trololo(@QueryParam("sort") final String sort , @QueryParam("search") final String search) {
return new MyReturnClass(sort, search);}
```